# Can I delete the contents of /var/lock?

Tags: delete

I am seeing some perculiar files in the directory /var/lock, how do I delete the contents of the file?

Comment: Which peculiar files?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo rm`?

Comment: Why do you mope around  /var/lock ? any particular reason ?

Answer (score 2):

```
phani@pinaki:/run$ ls -l /var/lock

 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Dec 31 22:08 /var/lock -> /run/lock
```

/var/lock in soft link to /run/lock where /run is mounted as tmpfs file system where kernel or applications keeps all pid (like /run/sshd.pid) files to track for their reference

Ubuntu has migrated away from /var/run, /var/lock and /dev/shm and now uses /run, /run/lock and /run/shm instead (respectively).

[Debian ReleaseGoals RunDirectory](https://wiki.debian.org/ReleaseGoals/RunDirectory)